# Append Sphinx Index?

Tags: sphinx

I have a site with about 2 Million records, a small portion of which are deleted each day along with a small number of new records. In other words the db changes slowly over time.

Currently I do "kill and fill" meaning I empty the table and re-import the records from my source and re-run the Sphinx configuration. In addition to the time element this creates inconsistencies between the database and the sphinx configuration during the several hour rotation.

Is there anyway for me to somehow just modify the index with the changed records? In other words if I add 100 records and delete 100 records to simply update the sphinx index accordingly vs having to re-rotate all the records?

Comment: Can your app use an RT index? You can then just run inserts/updates/deletes not only against your databases, but against Sphinx too to keep the data in sync.

Comment: I just started reading up on RT, trying to suss out the pros and cons vs Main/Delta. The platform runs with mysql/php so pretty sure we can RT. As far as I can tell since I've made the Main Index all I have to do is convert to RT (basically) and then have a script to specify which IDs to delete, which to modify and which to add once a day?  I'm also trying to find out which if any 'normal' Sphinx feautres if any are not RT compatible since it is a pretty complex config.

Comment: An RT index consists of plain indexes internally, so all features of plain indexes are compatible with RT. RT just encapsulates main+delta+kill-lists, but still you have to do some manual work: run OPTIMIZE when needed and decide or rt_mem_limit to limit RAM usage by RAM chunk. Besides that I can't think if anything which won't work with RT. If your app doesn't depend on rapid indexing which indexer+plain indexes provide or even if it does, but you can do ATTACH then RT is a way to go.

Comment: Hmm any type of daily manual work will NG the whole thing. Our import and various post import processes are all fully automated so having someone know when to jump in when done and update it won't work. Ideally we can just add a script to the end of the import and post-import processes that will then compare for new, delate, modify and run the new records for RT. Is that a pipe dream?

Comment: If it's easy to "compare for new, delate, modify and run" and you already use plain indexes then the easiest you can do is just add another delta index and put the modified docs into that. Then you optionally can do indexer --merge to merge the changes in your main index.